# Why does selenium .click() open a JavaScript rendered page in a new tab?

Tags: asp.net, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, click

I am writing a web scraper for a page build with asp.net and there are links in the page that are JavaScript rendered with a doPostBack call like this:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$SearchResults','openDetails$0')">2019CP2300054</a>
```

When I click on the link with Selenium, like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, case_num)))
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, case_num).click()
```

The link opens in a new tab in my web driver instance. I am not control-clicking. When I click the link in my browser, it renders the page on the same tab.

Let me know if I need to provide any more details! I am new to web scraping.

I have tried a few things, but I can't figure out what is making this behavior happen. Searching Stack Overflow yields a lot of results from folks trying to open the page in a new tab, and I am trying to do the opposite.

[Picture of the new tab behavior happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPk9a.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript on the webpage might be adding event-handlers, such as "OnClick", to the link.